# R Shiny: interactive SQL Query (elegant way of multiple filtering in SQL)

Tags: sql, r, shiny

I am trying to figure out elegant way of multiple filtering in SQL Query. I would like the user to have option to filter one column in database for one or more values (at the moment i am only able to create two separate SQL Queries, which one filter using one value, another two).

Here is an example of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ROracle)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",
                         tabPanel("Test",
                                  sidebarLayout(
                                    sidebarPanel(
                                      textInput("drv", "Database Driver", value="Oracle"),
                                      textInput("user", "User ID"),
                                      passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                                      actionButton("connectDB", "Connect to DB")) ,
                                    mainPanel(
                                      textOutput("test"),
                                      wellPanel(
                                        h4(strong("Filtering:")),
                                        br(),
                                        radioButtons('sqlfilter', 'Filter:',
                                                     choices = list("1 x OrdNr" = 1, 
                                                                    "2 x OrdNr" = 2),
                                                     selected = 1,inline=TRUE),
                                        conditionalPanel(
                                          condition = "input.sqlfilter == '1' | input.sqlfilter == '2' ", uiOutput("ordnr_ui")),
                                        conditionalPanel(
                                          condition = "input.sqlfilter == '2' ", uiOutput("ordnr2_ui"))
                                        actionButton("button1", "Auswaehlen"))
                                    ))
                         )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  con=reactiveValues(cc=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$connectDB,{
    if(input$drv != "Oracle"){
      con$cc="Only 'Oracle' implemented currently"
    }else{
      drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
      con$cc<- dbConnect(drv,input$host,username=input$user,password=input$passwd) #1st Query
    }
  })
  observe({
    if(!is.null(con$cc)& is(con$cc,"OraConnection")){ # check if connected/very slow...
      output$test <- renderText({
        HTML(paste0(tags$span(style="color:green","Verbindung zur"),"<br>","<b>", tags$span(style="color:green","Kawasi Datenbank, Schema S_BLOCKTEMP_SEG_ALL_KB"),"</b>","<br>",tags$span(style="color:green","erfolgreich hergestellt")))
      })

      rs <- dbSendQuery(con$cc, "Select distinct a From x.y order by x asc")
      ordnnrlist <- fetch(rs)

      output$ordnr_ui=renderUI({selectInput("ordnr", label = "OrdNr_1:", choices = ordnnrlist$a, selected="",multiple=FALSE)})
      utput$ordnr2_ui=renderUI({selectInput("ordnr2", label = "OrdNr_2:", choices = ordnnrlist$a, selected="",multiple=FALSE)})

      sqlOutput <- reactive({

        if(input$sqlfilter == 1){ 
          sqlInput <- paste("select * from x.y where x.y.a =",input$ordnr)
          }else{
            sqlInput <-  paste("select * from x.y where ((a =",input$ordnr, ") or (a =",input$ordnr2, "))")}
        dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput))}


    }else if (!is.null(con$cc) ){
      output$test <- renderText({
        con$cc
      })
    }
  })


  session$onSessionEnded(function() { 
    observe({
      if(!is.null(con$cc)& is(con$cc,"OraConnection")){# check if connected
        print(paste0("disconnect ",dbDisconnect(con$cc)))}
    }) 
  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

As we can see i have `radioButtons` widget which gives user an option if wanna filter one value from column OrdNr or two  --> that leads to two SQL Queries (dependent on the choosen filtering option from `radioButtons`):

```
if(input$sqlfilter == 1){ 
          sqlInput <- paste("select * from x.y where x.y.ORDNR =",input$ordnr)
          }else{
            sqlInput <-  paste("select * from x.y where ((ORDNR =",input$ordnr, ") or (ORDNR =",input$ordnr2, "))")}
        dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput))}
```

What if i want the user to have possibility to choose three or four values from column OrdNr? **Do I really need four SQL Queries?**

Is there a way to make it more elegant? Like one SQL Query in which selectInput would be `multiple=TRUE` with some kind of `collapse` option:

```
output$ordnr_ui=renderUI({selectInput("ordnr", label = "OrdNr_1:", choices = ordnnrlist$a, selected="",multiple=TRUE)})
```

??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into the sql syntax for `WHERE ORDNR IN ([opt1], [opt2], ..., [optn])`

Comment: i am not yet very good with programming, one question how i can access all elements from `selectInput`? and not in this case using input$ordnr[1], input$ordnr[2]... It should be dynamic

Comment: `selectInput` with `multiple = TRUE` returns a vector, so you may create a string of the selected items with `paste(input$ordnr, collapse=", ")` to make a SQL style list.  If you are working with strings, you may need to use `collapse = ', '` to get the query syntax right.

Comment: Thanks!It works perfectly!